# Prevent a manual install of firefox to autoupdate like in Linux distros

Tags: linux, firefox

I have a manual install of Firefox, and I would like it to prevent to autoupdate (my need is to stick some Selenium version).

When Firefox is packaged in Linux distro, this feature is  deactivated. This is obviously for letting the package manager do the updates.

I would like to do the same, but I couldn't find how the distro disable Firefox's autoupdate feature.
Can anyone explain me how it works ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox type `about:config` into the address bar and press Enter. Filter the list to find `app.update.auto` and set it to `false`. Do the same for `app.update.enabled` and set to `false`.

See here for info: http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.auto